# Javascript sort array by criteria

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array of objects. Each object has a Name, Surname, Phone, PostCode etc. My aim is to sort this array by passing criteria (sort either ASC or DESC).

```
filterBy(criteria) {    
    this.items.sort(by_criteria)  
}
```

So when I pass "Name" as a criteria, it will sort it by Name etc.

I cannot find the way to apply on each spesific element of the object. 
How could I say for exaple:

```
1)(click)=filterBy("name");

2)    filterBy(criteria) {    
        this.items.sort(this.items.criteria)  
    }
```

What is the most elegant/easy/right way to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: sort by name? how ASC or DESC ? explain more. please read [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: Please share your current attempt.

Comment: Pass your corresponding sorting function to the `.sort` function based on the `criteria`